# How to disable the light that appears when touching a UIBarButtonItem?

Tags: iphone, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem

I have a toolbar with a `UIBarButtonItem` with style: `UIBarButtonItemStylePlain`.
I wonder how can I disable the light that appears while touching it?

`UIButton` has `showsTouchWhenHighlighted` property but there is no such a thing for `UIBarButtonItem` is there a work-around you might know?

Comment: iPhone users would expect such a flash effect when they press a toolbar button, I would discourage you from removing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Interface Builder drag a `UIButton` to the toolbar. It will create a `UIBarButtonItem` with a `UIButton` in it. Set the type of the `UIButton` to custom. Then you can fully customize the appearence. For example change the text color to white and the background color to transparent and of course disable the highlighting.

Comment: I can remember there used to be a setting, but it seems to be vanished from InterfaceBuilder in Xcode 4.x.

Answer (score 0):

You can also drop in a UITextField and make it non-editable.