# How to remove/avoid small white splash light on UIBarButtonItem programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

My issue is same as question: [How to disable the the light that appears when touching a UIBarButtonItem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955089/how-to-disable-the-the-light-that-appears-when-touching-a-uibarbuttonitem)

I have read answer if we use Interface builder. What if I add toolbar programmatically? How can I avoid the light on the bar button item?

Comment: you can do the same as in the answer, just do it programmatically. Add the button programmatically and customize it (programmatically)

Comment: I found the solution. I created a UILabel object and made its text as the title I needed. Then I created a UIBarButtonItem and given its customView with the created UILAble object. You could set any font for that UILabel and it will reflect accordingly.

Thank you all. :)

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want programatically you can do

```
    UIBarButtonItem *item;
    UIButton *b2=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [b2 addTarget:self action:@selector(settings:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   //you can set the background image or whatnot
    [b2 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settings.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
    item=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:b2];
      //then set the button on the UIToolbar through the items property
```