# remove light on UIBarButtonItem programatically when pressed?

Tags: ios, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem, popover

I know I can create a UIButton and init the UIBarButtonItem with the UIButton. With this solution we can avoid the problem.

Here the solution:

[How to remove/avoid small white splash light on UIBarButtonItem programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170641/how-to-remove-avoid-small-white-splash-light-on-uibarbuttonitem-programatically)

But I need the UIBarButtonItem for call a Popover, and popovers can only be calls from a UIBarButtonItem

```
[self.myPickerPopover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
```

**presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender**

Then when I'm trying to use the UIButton solution the application crash because I'm presenting the Popover from a Button and not from a BarButtonItem.

Any idea to solve the problem? Any idea to delete the light?

Thanks

Comment: But you still have an UIBarButtonItem as the "superview" of your UIButton, right? You're just setting the UIButton as the customView of the UIBarButtonItem. Have you tried to call presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem for the UIButtons's superview UIBarButtonItem ?

Comment: See this on how to get the UIBarButtonItem from the UIButton: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9578399/1691231

Comment: You are right the solution was easy. Just:  [self.myPickerPopover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:MY BAR BUTTON ITEM HERE (not the sender) permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES]; Thanks

Comment: I've put my comments in an answer, please accept it so that this question does not appear as unanswered on the questions list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem for the UIBarButtonItem instead of your UIButton.

```
[self.myPickerPopover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:--UIBarButtonItem here, not UIButton -- permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
```

See this on how to get the UIBarButtonItem from the UIButton: 
[stackoverflow.com/a/9578399/1691231](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9578399/1691231)